# HttpProtocol setting in web.config - valid also for SSL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, clickjacking

For preventing clickjacking attacks I've put this in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  ...
</system.webServer>
```

But my page is served over secure protocol, https. I also have this in web.config:

```
<system.web>
        <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name=".AUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" requireSSL="true" />
        </authentication>
</system.web>
```

I wonder if my page served over secure protocol is protected against clickjacking even if custom headers are inside httpProtocol section?

Comment: Cannot you set up experiments to assert? Settings in `httpProtocol` section apply to any valid connections (HTTP or HTTPS).

Comment: @LexLi - how do you know that? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: There won't be explicit documentation on that, as most IIS settings apply to both HTTP and HTTPS (and it becomes common sense). That's exactly why I asked you to experiment out, as that's the only solid way to tell.

Comment: @LexLi - I've learned something new today. Please post as answer, so I can mark as solution.

Comment: It you enable failed request tracing and monitor the https request, you will see that response header get injected during IIS intergrated pipeline. it is injected before IIS encrypt and return the response. So it work for both http and https.